# Assigning a pointer to the exact next memory address of an int

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to assign a pointer to the exact next memory address of an int number and give it the doubled value of the number. However i can only write after 3(*4 which is the size of int) or more memory addresses,else it doesnt print anything.

That works

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int x, *ptr, memory_jump = 3;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    ptr = &x+memory_jump;
    *ptr = x * 2;
    printf("Given int = %d, Address = %d \nNext address content = %d,Next address pos = %d",x,&x,*ptr,ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

If i lower the memory jump to 2 or 1 it doesnt print anything at all so an error occurs.

```
int main(){
    int x, *ptr, memory_jump = 2;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    ptr = &x+memory_jump;
    *ptr = x * 2;
    printf("%d", (ptr-2));
    printf("Given int = %d, Address = %d \nNext address content = %d,Next address pos = %d",x,&x,*ptr,ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone explain what happens with these 2 next memory addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "experiments" are flawed.

In both cases, you are accessing memory locations and assigning values as if there's a valid `int` object at those locations. And both are [undefined behaviour.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: You are right but in the first case the output is the exact same when i tried it in different pc's. Does that still mean it is undefined behaviour?

Comment: Undefined behaviour isn't defined by what "appears to work", if behaviour is undefined according to the language specification, it's undefined. It may work or it may crash and burn, and you have no safe assurances that it won't do just that! (further reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)

Comment: Okay and one more question, can these memory addresses contain information about the int, like char arrays have the \0 to indicate the end of the array?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't think char arrays have a null terminator, you are thinking of C null-terminated strings, which are not quite the same thing.

`const char* str = "cheese";` has a null terminator, but 
`char str[42];` does not.